# White-space parameter value is not a valid input in Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, web-services

In my ASP.NET Core Web SDK (net7.0) project I have a controller with a Get method that accepts multiple string parameters.
`public async Task<ActionResult<SomethingDetailDTO>> GetSomethingById(string param1, string param2, string param3){...}`

However when I make an API call
"https://{{server}}:{{port}}/api/Something/GetSomethingById/param1value/   /param3value"
I get a validation error:

```
    {
        "errors": {
            "param2": [
                "The param2 field is required."
            ]
        }
    }
```

**On API call whitespace gets converted to `null` on the server (not on the client)
In my case whitespace is a valid input. How can I accept whitespace-s for this parameter name on all API-s?**

Similar to (but not the same project):
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64660482/web-api-whitespace-parameter-value-being-converted-to-null](https://stackoverflow.com)

I have tried the following:

1. nullable string `param2?`

- I don't want to define this wherever I use this specific parameter. I don't know how many whitespaces are being sent.

2. [FromQuery]

- I don't want to define this wherever I use this specific parameter. And I don't want to eat into URL space with the parameter name. I don't know how many whitespaces are being sent.
  `public async Task<ActionResult<SomethingDetailDTO>> GetSomethingById(string param1, string param3, [FromQuery] string param2 = "")`
  "https://{{server}}:{{port}}/api/Something/GetSomethingById/param1value/param3value?param2=   "

3. [FromBody]

- Get method can't have a body in request. I could change the method to Post, but I still can have only one parameter in body.

4. Also, I don't want to create a complex type (class) for a "simple" input.
5. Configure controllers to not have required inputs in my Program pipeline

- Wrong: I still want that other parameters are mandatory input.
  Also this just converts multiple spaces to none "   " -> ""

```
    builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true;
    });
```

6. I can't use the answer in similar issue because it is a different project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model binder will convert the space to null and show the error. If you want to solve this issue, you should create a custom model binder to achieve this specific requirement.

You could create a new class like this:

```
public class SpaceModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(null);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        value = value.Replace("%20", " ");

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(value);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> WhitSpaceTest([FromQuery]string param1, [FromQuery, ModelBinder(typeof(SpaceModelBinder))] string param2, [FromQuery] string param3) {
```

Result

[image]

---

If you want to let this binder work for global, please create a binder provider and use it inside the program.cs

```
public class AuthorEntityBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(string))
        {
            return new SpaceModelBinder();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Program.cs register it

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new AuthorEntityBinderProvider());

 
});
```

Comment: I am avoiding "FromQuery" as I would like to use URL part (before "?") and I would like to set and forget the configuration for param2 that would apply for all API methods (globaly). So binding it on the method is not enaugh for me
Is there any other way to use SpaceModelBinder on all API methods that have a string parameter named parameter2.

Comment: If you want to let this binder work for all method you should create a custom model binder provider and register it inside the UseMVC or UseController service.Please check my update answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will further modify AuthorEntityBinderProvider to use SpaceModelBinder only for specific parameter names provided in context metadata.